# can we override start field with custom fields in event object

Tags: apex, trigger

can we put custom date field & custom picklist field with no's in it. IN start(SartDateTime) field in event object with trigger code. plz can any one provide me with a sample code please

when event is created for opportunity, date field and picklist field should override the star feild and populate the custom fields values.

Comment: Do you want to autopopulate a date field and a picklist in an event related to an opportunity when the event is being created? Your question is too confusing to understand what you really want !!!

Comment: sorry nothing related to opportunity im sorry abt that. i have a 2 custom fields in event object 1 is date field ohter is pick list field when event is created start field is default field we cannot save the record with out values in it so i want to override the start field with those custom fields

Comment: This is doable by overriding the newevent button with a vf page where we can pass the start value through the URLFOR() and using $Action.The part I do not get is when you say you On create the other 2 fields need to be copied over to the event start date, where will the other 2 fields get the value from?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create a VF page like : New_event_Override:

```
<apex:page standardController="event" action="{!urlredirect}" extensions="event_override">
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public with sharing class event_override {
public date custom_date;
public string custom_picklistval;
    public event_override(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    custom_date = date.newInstance(2012, 11, 30);
    custom_picklistval = '07:00 AM';
    }
    public pagereference urlredirect(){
    Pagereference page = new pagereference('/00U/e');
    page.getparameters().put('StartDateTime',string.valueof(custom_date.format()));
    page.getparameters().put('StartDateTime_time',custom_picklistval);
    page.setredirect(true);
    return page;
    }
}
```

NOTE : The way I get the 'StartDateTime' and 'StartDateTime_time' is by going to the input field next to the start right clicking on the field and inspecting element in chrome ( this gives the Id of the field , which we can override)

Comment: Hi rao, can we do this operation with trigger

Comment: populating data on trigger on create is possible, pl breif more on what you want so that i can try to help you.

Comment: in the event field start is the mandatory field without entering the values we cant save the record. what im looking for is i created a date field(Date__c) and time__c fiels(Picklist with hours ex: 01,02,03...59) after entering the values & click save values of date field and time field should display in start field with over riding the start values